# In HTML5, can you nest NAV elements?

Tags: html, coding-style

I have a site-wide main menu, which I'm currently using `<nav>` for. I also have a submenu, which is right under the main nav and is different for every *product* on the site. What's the best practice to handle this?

Currently, I have a separate `<div id="secondary-nav">` below the main nav. But since they're both within the `<header>` of the page, I was thinking about having a nested `<nav>` instead. Is this an OK practice in HTML5?

Comment: The content model for NAV elements is *Flow content*, and NAV elements themselves are *Flow content* [Source](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-nav-element).

Comment: @Jam *"The content model for NAV elements is Flow content"* = NAV elements can contain elements which are defined as *Flow content*. Since NAV elements themselves are defined as *Flow content*, that means that NAV elements can contain NAV elements.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't mean to sound so harsh. I was wondering what a "flow element" is. Is it a block element, as opposed to `display: inline`, or is it `position: static` as opposed to `position: fixed` for example. Basically, do flow elements contribute to the flow of the page?

Comment: @JamWaffles - "What's a flow element" is  non-trivial to explain. It probably warrants a separate SO question.

Comment: Oh ok. I'll leave it at that then :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable to use `nav` there. You may also want to look at `aside` if it can be removed, or look to use `section` tags within the `nav` to better divide up the content. This returns to the whole semantics debate, where my stance is, if it makes sense, do it. It doesn't need to be 100% semantically correct, as no one outside of the people who look at source code will ever know.

Comment: The point of semantics is not to have good looking markup, but to add additional functionality to the markup. By creating semantic markup, you're building a structure that can be universally understood by screen readers, search engines, etc.

Comment: @thirdender I agree that markup should be correct and functional, but markup that looks good is often also technically ok ("If it looks good, it will fly good."). After all, markup languages are meant to be readable for *both* humans and machines.

Comment: True. I guess what I was trying to say (after re-reading my comment a year later :-p) is that semantics is about enhancing the _meaning_ of markup. If semantics doesn't matter, then a `<div>` and a `<nav>` are both equally "readable". The reason we use `<nav>` in some places is to enhance the _meaning_ of that section of markup. Done properly, search engines and accessibility technologies have a heightened awareness of page content and structure. A search engine goes "aha! navigation", a screen reader announces "here's a menu".

Comment: Yeah semantics are about enhancing the meaning. But this idea that it can then be universally understood is a long way removed from reality. In reality screen readers, search engines et al have developed their own 'extensions' to HTML and are using that (e.g. ARIA roles, microformats, sitemap.xml etc) in combination with their own tricks to interpret the markup. They hardly rely on the semantics of the elements because it is so often used wrong. It turns out that the original comment that 'no one outside the people looking at your source will ever know' is actually very close to the truth.

Comment: This is incorrect and doesnt answer the question.

Comment: "as no one outside of the people who look at source code will ever know" - if your site wont ever be used, thats true. Otherwise a false statement

Answer (score 14):

There is currently nothing in the specs that indicates that nesting `nav`s is not allowed. And seeing as `<nav>` is a block-level element, there is nothing wrong with nesting them.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to web accessibility...

NVDA screen reader software seems to handle nested landmarks such as a nav inside a header. NVDA short cut keys still work with nested landmark elements.

"Landmark roles can be nested to identify parent/child relationships of the information being presented."

"If a page includes more than one navigation landmark, each should have a unique label."

"If a navigation landmark has an identical set of links as another navigation landmark on the page, use the same label for each navigation landmark."

[ARIA Landmarks Example](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/landmarks/examples/HTML5.html)

I would say, based on that information, nested navs may be quite appropriate when you have submenus.